# git push .git/description file

Tags: git, gitweb

Is it possible to push the changes in the `.git` directory to a remote repository?

I wish to have a common project `description` and not have to re-enter it for all the clones of my repository.

It's strange that the project description is something that is not common to each clone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could store a `description` (or `.description`, if you don't want it to be visible) in the root of your repo, and then symlink `.git/description` to that in each repo, like so:

```
repo/
  .description
  .git/
    description -> ../.description
```

You'd have to set up the symlink manually in each of your repos, but you'd only have to do that once (when the repo is created).

Or you could use a post-receive [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to copy your tracked description file into `.git/description`. You'd have to set up that hook on each remote repo, too, but again, that would only need to happen once (when the repo is created).

Comment: Works depending of the current branch nop ? And what for a `bare` repo ? No way ?