# updating description of project in bare repository

Tags: git

Is there a way to update project description in bare repository. I have cloned the project , updated description and tried git push. But description is not getting updated. I'm using gitolite in my environment.

Comment: Added file called description in bare repo and it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git push .git/description file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214871/git-push-git-description-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description file isn't synced between repos.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214871/git-push-git-description-file) is an alternate method to simulate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just added one file called description in bare repo and it started working fine,.

Comment: It's syncing the .git/description file? Or a file called description in the working dir?

Comment: You are correct,  only in gitweb it showed the description not in newly cloned one. Tested your solution which worked. Again thanks.