# Upload locally modified GIT description file to remote

Tags: git

I would like to upload a locally modified GIT description file (i.e.: `.git/description`) to the remote.

For testing purpose, I created a brand new bare local repository:

```bash
$ mkdir test-remote && cd $_
$ git init --bare
```

Then, I:

- cloned it to a specific directory.
- made some changes to the cloned `.git/description`.
- created an empty commit on a new `master` branch.
- pushed `master` changes to `origin`.

```bash
$ git clone --local ./test-remote test
$ git checkout -b master
$ echo "TEST" > .git/description
$ git status
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit."
$ git push origin master
```

However, I noticed that changes to `.git/description` don't appear in `git status` and does not appear in `origin`'s local files after `push` either..

Is this file expected to be modified on the remote-side only? Is there a way to modify it locally and then upload it to the remote?

Although this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214871/git-push-git-description-file) provides a good answer, the post is 12 years old and the solution is a bit tedious (creating symbolic links) regarding the number of repositories I own. Is there anything that could help in newer GIT versions?

Comment: The files inside `.git` are not tracked, because they are the inner workings of the repo itself.

Comment: You'd have to access the server itself and copy files manually, git won't do that for you I'm afraid.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't really expect git to show this file in the git status. However, I was hoping it to "silently" push it to remote as part of its core files..

Comment: @RomainValeri I was hoping git to "silently" push it to remote as part of its core files..

Comment: Nothing changed in passed 12 years. Either you copy the file to the working tree outside of `.git/` and then add+commit+push. Or you copy the file with tools beyond `git`.

Comment: @phd Too bad, I will go with editing files directly on the remote side then .. Thank you to the three of you for your time :)